# How to convert an int64 to int in Go?

Tags: go, int, int64

In Go, what is the best strategy for converting `int64` to `int`? I am having difficulty comparing the two

```
package main 

import (
    "math"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

type largestPrimeFactor struct {
    N      int
    Result int
}

func main() {
    base := largestPrimeFactor{N:13195}
    max := math.Sqrt(float64(base.N))

    maxStr := strconv.FormatFloat(max, 'E', 'G', 64)
    maxShift := strings.Split(maxStr, ".")[0]
    maxInt, err := strconv.ParseInt(maxShift, 10, 64)

    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err)
    }
```

on this next line

```
    for a := 2; a < maxInt; a++ {
        if isPrime(a) {
            if base.N % a == 0 {
                base.Result = a
            }
        }
    }

    println(base)
}

func isPrime(n int) bool {
    flag := false

    max := math.Sqrt(float64(n))

    maxStr := strconv.FormatFloat(max, 'E', 'G', 64)
    maxShift := strings.Split(maxStr, ".")[0]
    maxInt, err := strconv.ParseInt(maxShift, 10, 64)

    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err)
    }

    for a := 2; a < maxInt; a++ {
        if (n % a == 0) {
            flag := true
        }
    }
    return flag
}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You convert them with a type ["conversion"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

```
var a int
var b int64
int64(a) < b
```

When comparing values, you always want to convert the smaller type to the larger. Converting the other way will possibly truncate the value:

```
var x int32 = 0
var y int64 = math.MaxInt32 + 1 // y == 2147483648
if x < int32(y) {
// this evaluates to false, because int32(y) is -2147483648
```

Or in your case to convert the `maxInt` `int64` value to an `int`, you could use

```
for a := 2; a < int(maxInt); a++ {
```

which would fail to execute correctly if `maxInt` overflows the max value of the `int` type on your system.

Comment: @pward here's a starting point for number types in go that might help https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types

Comment: Why is it correct to assume that `int64` is bigger than `int`?

Comment: @ceving, it's not, it's correct to assume that `int64` is larger or _equal_ in _size_ to `int`, therefor converting from `int` to `int64` will never lose data, which is not true of the inverse case.

Comment: @JimB `int` is CPU specific. It is not correct to assume that a 128 bit CPU will never exist in the future.

Comment: @ceving: we are not talking about theoretical future CPU architectures, we are talking about the [Go language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Numeric_types), which states that `int` and `uint` are either 32 or 64 bits.

Answer (score 31):

I came here because of the title, ***"How to convert an int64 to int in Go?"***. The answer is,

```
int(int64Var)
```

Comment: Had a doubt but verified this is a lossless conversion https://go.dev/play/p/DjuxXVsysKy